# AWS ELB Took too long to respond when routing to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an Application Load Balancer configured to forward all traffic on port 443 to port 80 in an Elastic Beanstalk application running Angular 8 (server rendered) and .NET Core (VS Template). There is also a redirect setup from 80 on load balancer to 443 on load balancer for SSL redirection.

Additionally I have DNS domain xyz.com registered and pointing to the load balancer.

When I try to navigate to the xyz.com page I however get:
I am getting "site took too long to respond."

After around 2 minutes loading.

I checked the security groups but I don't see anything concrete.

Comment: did you check the response time without LB? or did you try to hit LB endpoint with DNS ?

Comment: All fine @Adiii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been long solved.

Apparently I've been looking at the Security Groups in the wrong Region. Switched to the right ones and it indeed had incorrect entry which was changed.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a bit more information, whoever will be looking for. There are might be few reasons and most frequently:

- You specified Subnet (and/or Security  Group) for your Load Balancer/Target Groups which is located in another region from your users requests.

*Because your request have route from different region, it will take some time to perform action. And that's why you had this delay.*